# Does $L^2$ convergence and convergence on a countable dense subset, together imply almost everywhere convergence?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ be a domain with smooth boundary. Let $\psi:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function of bounded variation. Let $D\subset\Omega$ be a countable dense subset such that $\psi$ is continuous at all $x\in D$. There is a sequence of smooth functions $\{f_n\}$ such that as $n\to\infty$,$\|f_n-\psi\|_{L^2(\Omega)} = 0$. It is also given that $\forall x\in D$  as $n\to\infty$,$f_n(x)\to\psi(x)$.

I want to prove that $f_n\to \psi$ almost everywhere. Appreciate any hints/help.

Comment: cross post: https://mathoverflow.net/q/381985/14414